# Flutter Expansion Tile not opening from card list view on tap

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list view which are list of card build dynamically. In one part of the card I put one column and put an arrow down button/icon. On click I want to open more details in an expansion tile. So I create a widget function for it. I notice the function is being called cause I put a print in it but the expansion tile is not being build right below the card.

First part is here I build my dynamic cards.

```
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                               return new Container(

                                margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 20, 0),
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                          //color:Color.fromRGBO(255, 255,255, 1),
                                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                                            topRight: const Radius.circular(35),
                                                            bottomRight: const Radius.circular(35)
                                                          ),

                                ),
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 55,
                                child:Card(
                                    elevation: 5,
                                    //color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                                                topRight: const Radius.circular(35),
                                                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(35)
                                        ), 
                                   ),

                                   child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[



                                      Container(
                                        width: 90,

                                        child:
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          children: [ 
                                          Column(
                                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          children: [ 
                                          //new Row( 
                                          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, 

                                          //children: <Widget>[ 
                                          new Text( 
                                          "200", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.blue),
                                          ), 
                                          new Text( 
                                          "mmm", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black),
                                          ), 
                                        // new Icon(Icons.account_circle) 
                                          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2 

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                          Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                                            children: [
                                               GestureDetector( 
                                               onTap: () { 
                                                   print("Calling expansion tile");
                                                   expansionList(context,index);
                                                },
                                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),  
                                              ) 



                                            ]
                                          )
                                          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2 

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ]
                                   )
                                )
                               );
                          }
```

Thus on tap function I call this function expansionList(context,index); which I have shown below the details of the function. But the tile is not being open. How to make the tile to open dynamically on tap.

```
Widget expansionList(BuildContext context, int index) {
  print("In expansion tile");
    return new ExpansionTile(

      title: Text(
        "TEST",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
          Column(
                                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                                      children: [ 
                                      //new Row( 
                                      // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, 

                                      //children: <Widget>[ 
                                      new Text( 
                                      "200", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.blue),
                                      ), 
                                      new Text( 
                                      "mmm", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black),
                                      ), 
                                    // new Icon(Icons.account_circle) 
                                      //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2 

                                      ],
               ),


           ]


    );
}
```

Comment: @KiroConeski I dont quite get your on the Widget to stateful one. I dont quite on your logic either.

Comment: sorry @newbie. I misunderstood your question, that's why I deleted the comment. But, please read the ExpandedTile documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample. What you are trying to implement with the above code, is your own Expanded Tile logic. You're not using it as you should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do now is - on each click you:

- call print method - it prints to console.
- call a function that returns `ExpansionTile` widget.

But you do nothing with the returned value, it doesn't even has a chance to get into your widget tree, it's simply built and nothing done with it.

`ExpansionTile` is a widget which consists of:

- 3 slots each can hold Widget(or tree):

  1. Widget `leading` - usually you place avatar/icon/checkbox here
  2. Widget `title` - main content of a tile
  3. Widget `trailing` - the end of tile, best place for dropdown arrow (included in ExpansionTile by default)
- and a `children` array - what is shown when expanded;

Code:

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
        return new Container(
          margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 20, 0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            //color:Color.fromRGBO(255, 255,255, 1),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: const Radius.circular(35),
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(35)),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          // height: 55,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(35),
                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(35)),
            ),
            child: expansionList(ctxt, index),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
    }
```

And place whatever you want on collapsed tile in `leading` and `title`, if you want customize the arrow - use custom `trailing`.

```
  Widget expansionList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    print("Building expansion tile");
    return new ExpansionTile(
      initiallyExpanded: false,
      leading: Icon(Icons.all_inclusive),    
      title: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Content'),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          Text('Row 1'),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Content row 2'),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Content row 3')
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.network(
      "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png",
      height: 55,
    ),
  ],
    );
  }
```

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/FPpU31paQvrOgPpaAx/giphy.gif]

*PS get familiar with code formatting hot-key combo, and always put trailing commas - the code will auto-format much nicer*

Comment: in my card I want to have more section/column and only the last section I want to have the down arrow and on click of it I want to show details

Comment: Are you sure you need a card here? You are free to put columns/rows/whatever in `title` slot

Comment: beside card what else could I design with round shape on the top right and bottom right. I need one section for date one section for details and one section to show distance travelled and beside it I want the down arrow

Comment: I mean, you don't want to put all content in `Card`, instead you put content into `title` of `ExpansionTile`, and put the whole  `ExpansionTile` as the only child of `Card`. Well, try to launch my code, it's already doing exactly what u ask for

Comment: I already launch and testing your codes but in my emulator it says bottom overflowed by 43 pixels and when I press the arrow nothing shows below and it again give that bottom overflowed by 11 pixels

Comment: make sure the height is not set, I've commented it out. If you limit the height of card - it clashes with the expanded widget height. instead your content dictates the height of a tile

Comment: ok I remove it works now. But can I not expand the whole card it looks ugly but to have the expanded section as rectangle container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189686/discussion-between-buffer-underflow-and-newbie).